# error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'vfs' because it is a read-only property

Tags: angular, pdfmake, vfs

**Im Trying to generate PDF using pdfmaker. In my code it dosent show any errors.but when compiling it show below error. but also pdf is working and generating.**

error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'vfs' because it is a read-only property.

```
>   19 pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
>                ~~~
>     src/app/component/invoice/invoice.component.ts:235:25 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ content: ({ text: string; fontSize:
> number; alignment: string; color: string; bold?: undefined;
> decoration?: undefined; style?: undefined; columns?: undefined; } | {
> text: string; fontSize: number; bold: boolean; ... 4 more ...;
> columns?: undefined; } | { ...; } | { ...; })[]; styles: { ...; }; }'
> is not assignable to parameter of type 'TDocumentDefinitions'.
>       Types of property 'content' are incompatible.
>         Type '({ text: string; fontSize: number; alignment: string; color: string; bold?: undefined; decoration?: undefined; style?:
> undefined; columns?: undefined; } | { text: string; fontSize: number;
> bold: boolean; ... 4 more ...; columns?: undefined; } | { ...; } | {
> ...; })[]' is not assignable to type 'Content'. 
>           Type '({ text: string; fontSize: number; alignment: string; color: string; bold?: undefined; decoration?: undefined; style?:
> undefined; columns?: undefined; } | { text: string; fontSize: number;
> bold: boolean; ... 4 more ...; columns?: undefined; } | { ...; } | {
> ...; })[]' is not assignable to type 'ArrayOfContent'.
>             The types returned by 'pop()' are incompatible between these types.
>               Type '{ text: string; fontSize: number; alignment: string; color: string; bold?: undefined; decoration?: undefined;
> style?: undefined; columns?: undefined; } | { text: string; fontSize:
> number; bold: boolean; ... 4 more ...; columns?: undefined; } | { ...;
> } | { ...; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string |
> ArrayOfContent | ContentText | ContentColumns | ContentStack |
> ContentUnorderedList | ... 11 more ... | undefined'.
>                 Type '{ text: string; fontSize: number; alignment: string; color: string; bold?: undefined; decoration?: undefined;
> style?: undefined; columns?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type
> 'string | ArrayOfContent | ContentText | ContentColumns | ContentStack
> | ContentUnorderedList | ... 11 more ... | undefined'.
>                   Property 'tocItem' is missing in type '{ text: string; fontSize: number; alignment: string; color: string; bold?:
> undefined; decoration?: undefined; style?: undefined; columns?:
> undefined; }' but required in type 'ContentTocItem'.
>     
>     235       pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download();
>                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     
>       node_modules/@types/pdfmake/interfaces.d.ts:253:5
>         253     tocItem: boolean | string | string[];
>                 ~~~~~~~
>         'tocItem' is declared here.
>     src/app/component/invoice/invoice.component.ts:237:25 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ content: ({ text: string; fontSize:
> number; alignment: string; color: string; bold?: undefined;
> decoration?: undefined; style?: undefined; columns?: undefined; } | {
> text: string; fontSize: number; bold: boolean; ... 4 more ...;
> columns?: undefined; } | { ...; } | { ...; })[]; styles: { ...; }; }'
> is not assignable to parameter of type 'TDocumentDefinitions'.
>     
>     237       pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).print();
>                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     src/app/component/invoice/invoice.component.ts:239:25 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ content: ({ text: string; fontSize:
> number; alignment: string; color: string; bold?: undefined;
> decoration?: undefined; style?: undefined; columns?: undefined; } | {
> text: string; fontSize: number; bold: boolean; ... 4 more ...;
> columns?: undefined; } | { ...; } | { ...; })[]; styles: { ...; }; }'
> is not assignable to parameter of type 'TDocumentDefinitions'.
>     
>     239       pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
```

**This is my component.ts code and im using generatePDf function to generate pdf and its working fine and no error showing.**

```
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js';
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js';
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;


 generatePDF(action = "open") {
    let docDefinition = {
      content: [
        {
          text: "Indika Agro Sales and Service Center",
          fontSize: 16,
          alignment: "center",
          color: "#047886",
        },
        {
          text: "INVOICE",
          fontSize: 20,
          bold: true,
          alignment: "center",
          decoration: "underline",
          color: "skyblue",
        },
        {
          text: "Customer Details",
          style: "sectionHeader",
        },
        {
          columns: [
              [
                  {
                      text: this.invoiceform.value.customerName,
                      bold: true
                  },
                  { text:this.invoiceform.value.cusPhnNumber,  }
              ],
              [
                  {
                      text: `Date: ${new Date().toLocaleString()}`,
                      alignment: 'right'
                  },
                  {
                      text: `Bill No : ${((Math.random() * 1000).toFixed(0))}`,
                      alignment: 'right'
                  }
              ]
          ]
      },
      ],
      styles: {
        sectionHeader: {
          bold: true,
          decoration: "underline",
          fontSize: 14,
          margin: [0, 15, 0, 15],
        },
      },
    };

    if (action === "download") {
      pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download();
    } else if (action === "print") {
      pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).print();
    } else {
      pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a typing script ...:

```
import * as pdfMake from "pdfmake / build / pdfmake";
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake / build / vfs_fonts';

(pdfMake as any).vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```

Comment: Never mind about my last comment... I see that this is actually the approach recommended by their docs. That's an unfortunately ugly hack, but not the fault of the user.

Answer (score 0):

I was using vite to compile the react apps, and then it throws this error that vfs is read only property and cannot be assigned. What worked for me:
I copied the pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js to my src directory and changed the first line from:
`this.pdfMake=this.pdfMake||{};this.pdfMake.vfs={`

To
`const pdfFonts={`

Rest the file remains same, then at end I added default export:`export default pdfFonts;`

Then in the file where I want to use pdfmake to createpdf, I did this thing:

```
import pdfmake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import pdfFonts from './vfs_fonts';
pdfmake.vfs=pdfFonts;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using typescript, but the solution marked here did not work for me, and instead gave me this error:

> Cannot assign to import "vfs"

If you see this, the solution to use instead is:

```
import pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';

(pdfMake as any).vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```