# Using pdfmaker in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, stenciljs, pdfmake

I want to use to pdfmaker in my Stenciljs project and following the official Guideline here:

https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/getting-started/client-side/

as well as  previous question at stackoverflow:

[error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'vfs' because it is a read-only property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66124415/error-ts2540-cannot-assign-to-vfs-because-it-is-a-read-only-property)

I have first installed pdfmake via npm

```
 npm install pdfmake
```

Then I am trying to use it in a component which is called my-messages:

```
 import * as pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
 import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
 (pdfMake as any).vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```

My component wont even initialize and I keep getting the following the errors in Browser:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pdfMake')
at my-messages.entry.js:78239 undefined

index-2022e853.js:1949 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Constructor for "my-messages#undefined" 
was not found at initializeComponent
```

Comment: Yes, I see that now. It's unfortunate, but not your fault.

Comment: Thats one of the issues, if I do as in the official guideline (<any>pdfMake).vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs; , then I get JSX element <any> has no end tag  and the imports above are marked as unused, the code wont even compile via npm start

Comment: That's a known incompatibility between TypeScript and JSX. The solution, as recommended in the previous question, is to use TypeScript's alternative type assertion syntax (`... as any` is an alternative to `<any>...`, but they both do the same thing)

Comment: I don't understand why the PDFMake docs would suggest `import pdfMake` for JS but `import * as pdfMake` for TypeScript. That advice doesn't make sense. Try removing the `* as` syntax and see if that works.

Comment: import pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import  pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js';

(pdfMake as any).vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs; This leads to the next problem  Rollup: Missing Export 
'default' is not exported by ./node_modules/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js

Comment: Are you using webpack or TypeScript to build your JS files?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that that the `pdfMake` property could not be found on a a value because the value is undefined. This error is taking place in your compiled code (on line 78,239 in my-messages.entry.js).

Looking at the [source code for vfs_fonts](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/master/build/vfs_fonts.js), I can see the following lines that I believe are significant to your error.

First off, you can see where `pdfMake` is defined on your global (for example, `window` when running in a browser):

```
var _global =
  typeof window === 'object' ? window :
  typeof global === 'object' ? global :
  typeof self === 'object' ? self :
  this;
if (typeof _global.pdfMake !== 'undefined' && typeof _global.pdfMake.addVirtualFileSystem !== 'undefined') {
  _global.pdfMake.addVirtualFileSystem(vfs);
}
```

Next you can see a CommonJS-style export:

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = vfs;
}
```

Now, there are a lot of things that could be going wrong here, so the following is more of a starting place to investigate than a "this is definitely what's wrong".

You are trying to import the `vfs_fonts` module, but you are using a tool to build your TypeScript modules. That tool does not appear to be configured to support CommonJS-style modules (in other words, `module` is not defined), so `vfs_fonts` is returning `undefined` as its export.

I can't see exactly what's going on in your browser, but I suspect that when you try to read the `pdfMake` property on `pdfFonts`, you are getting a runtime error telling you that `pdfMake` doesn't exist on the `undefined` `pdfFonts` variable.

So you can either mess around with your compiler to find the right configuration to ensure CommonJS is supported (note that you might need to enable [allowJS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowJs) to read JS modules) or you can pull `pdfMake` off of the window (which might not work in all contexts, but *should* be ok if you are working in a browser). Something like the following *might* work: `(pdfMake as any).vfs = window.pdfMake.vfs;`